# how to join multiple joins in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using multiple joins but got stuck in this. I am using join of 3 tables but it fetches values of only 2 tables not 3rd one. Here my model query is:

```
public function seller_products()
{       
$this->db->select('*')->select('wc_seller_products.id')->from('wc_seller_products')
     ->join('wc_seller', 'wc_seller.id = wc_seller_products.seller_id', 'LEFT')
     ->join('wc_seller_info', 'wc_seller_info.id = wc_seller_products.seller_id', 'LEFT');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query;  
}
```

It doesn't fetch values of wc_seller table .... please help

Comment: what is error ? i think u need to pass table name with star `'wc_seller_info.*'`

Comment: it fetches wc_seller_products and wc_seller_info values.... shows blank where i want to fetch wc_seller values

Comment: also not working which you suggest to pass *

Comment: if shows blank check your log folder and today log file

Comment: i think sum other mistake in query.. cant getting

Answer (score 0):

```
public function seller_products()
   {       
       $this->db->select('wc_seller_products.*,wc_seller.*,wc_seller_info.*');
       $this->db->from('wc_seller_products');
       $this->db->join('wc_seller', 'wc_seller.id = wc_seller_products.seller_id');
       $this->db->join('wc_seller_info', 'wc_seller_info.id = wc_seller_products.seller_id');
       $query = $this->db->get();
       return $query;  
   }
```

Comment: by this function you can gate all data from all this 3 tables('wc_seller_products,wc_seller,wc_seller_info').if you want any one tables of data then you need to write it in select('').